# Bigquery data transfer doesn't run

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Bigquery to get data from FCM, but the data transfer doesn't run, it always stays pending

[run details of transfer data FCM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btE9t.png)

I'm using Flutter 1.17.5 and Firebase Messaging 7.0.3. Also, i already set this up:

[firebase docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JH2v.png)

I have no idea what else i can do. I already tried to setup the data transfer manually. Also waited for some days to see if the data was exported, and still doesn't work.

If someone could help me, i would appreciate very much

Comment: Could you attach the link to the Firebase documentation where that screenshot was taken from? What's the configuration for that transfer? (Configuraton Tab) Please, make sure that you remove sensitive fields

Comment: @Jay here's the link to the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery.

About the configuration for the transfer, it was all right, and still didn't work. But I was able to make it run by creating another dataset and creating another scheduled transfer. For some reason the dataset that was autocreated by bigquery wasn't working